# Type for useRef when used with setInterval/clearInterval [react-typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

I am setting up a useRef object to hold a NodeJS.Timeout component, the return type of setInterval(). When I use that later in clearInterval, I get an error (shown below) on both instances of intervalRef.current in the code.

What is the correct way to set this up so I can call clearInterval in the button onClick event?

```
function HookTimer(): ReactElement {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)

  let intervalRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer(prevTimer => prevTimer + 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      Hook Timer - {timer}    
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => clearInterval(intervalRef.current)}>Clear Hook Timer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(intervalId: Timeout): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Timeout | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Timeout'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(handle?: number | undefined): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Timeout | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.
> Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2769)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const intervalRef = React.useRef<null | NodeJS.Timeout>(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('runs every 2 seconds');
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
        console.log('clearInterval');
        return clearInterval(intervalRef.current as NodeJS.Timeout);
    };
}, []);
```

On initialization `intervalRef` is set to `null`.

`setInterval()` returns a NodeJS.Timeout type.

`clearInterval(handle)` definition says it expects the `handle` to be of type `number | undefined` (actually `NodeJS.Timeout | undefined`). As intervalRef.current could be of type null or NodeJS.Timout (as defined on intervalRef) we need to tell it that the handle should be treated as NodeJS.Timeout.

#### Update

Just for the sake of completeness: A very verbose alternative solution could be a guard:

```
// ...

React.useEffect(() => {
    // ...

    return () => {
        console.log('clearInterval');

        if (intervalRef.current !== null) {
            return clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        }
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: `NodeJS.Timeout` does not look correct to me in the browser context